# Menubar not being displayed in my GUI window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI program in Python using tkinter. My code is running error free but not displaying the menu widget i have included. I am unable to understand where am i going wrong!

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Menu, Canvas, Toplevel
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("app")

        menubar = Menu(master)
        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0) 
        file.add_command(label="Open")
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=master.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)

root = Tk()
my_gui = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the last bit, i.e. setting `root` to use your `menubar`.
From within the class you should, of course, use `master` to refer to `root`:

```
master.config(menu=menubar)
```

The full code now reads:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Menu, Canvas, Toplevel
class app:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("app")

        menubar = Menu(master)
        file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0) 
        file.add_command(label="Open")
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=master.quit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
        master.config(menu=menubar)

root = Tk()
my_gui = app(root)
root.mainloop()
```